# Invertability of Tensor Product of a Square Positive Definite Vandermonde Matrix with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Given the tensor product of a Invertable Square Positive-Definite Vandermonde Matrix $a$

$$\mathbf{a} = \
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 1 & \ldots & 1^{D-1} \\
 1 & 2 & \ldots & 2^{D-1} \\
 \vdots &  & \ddots & \vdots \\
 1 & D & \ldots & D^{D-1}  \\
\end{array} 
\right)$$

with itself:   $b = a\otimes a$.

Is b invertable?

And perhaps a bit more generally, if a is an invertable positive-definite matrix, but not necessarily a Vandermonde one, would $b$ be invertable?

Comment: Yes $b$ is invertible, assuming you are talking about the Kronecker product here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Properties

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the inverse of tensor product of invertible matrices is tensor product of inverse matrices. That is,
$$b^{-1}=(a\otimes a)^{-1}=a^{-1}\otimes a^{-1}$$
To verify,
$$(a\otimes a)(a^{-1}\otimes a^{-1})=(aa^{-1})\otimes(aa^{-1})=I_n\otimes I_n=I_{2n}$$
(The other direction is similar)